# linux + ksh  + Round down or Round up - float numbers

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk, ksh

in my ksh script I need to calculate only integer numbers

Sometimes I get float numbers such as 3.49 or 4.8...etc

so I need to translate the float numbers to integer’s numbers according to the following rules (examples)

```
3.49     will be 3
2.9      will be 3
4.1      will be 4
23.51    will be 24
982.4999 will be 982

10.5     will be 11  ( this example if float is .5 then it will roundup )
```

Please advice how to do this in ksh or awk or perl

Or

any other language that can be run in my ksh script

Comment: You did not give an "rules", just examples. And they leave the obvious question unanswered, namely, how to round when the decimal part is .500 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a brief google session, I found that `printf` seems to be able to do the job, at least in bash (couldn't find an online interpreter that does ksh).

```
printf "%0.f\n" 4.51
5
printf "%0.f\n" 4.49
4
```

Code at: http://ideone.com/nEFYF

Note: perl might be overkill, like Marius says, but here's a perl way:

The perl module [Math::Round](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Round) seems to handle the job.

**One-liner:**

```
perl -MMath::Round -we 'print round $ARGV[0]' 12.49
```

**Script:**

```
use v5.10;
use Math::Round;
my @list = (3.49, 2.9, 4.1, 23.51, 982.4999);

say round $_ for @list;
```

**Script output:**

```
3
3
4
24
982
```

Comment: Why not just use `printf "%0.f\n", $_ for @list;` with Perl?

Comment: @flesk That'd be `perl -nwe 'printf "%0.f\n", $_'` perhaps. Using `printf` directly is shorter, and handles one argument at the time, which sounded like what the OP wanted.

Comment: @TLP: I didn't even notice your Perl one-liner. If I had, I'd have suggested you replace it with `perl -e 'printf"%0.f\n",shift' 12.49`. What I meant was why use `Math::Round` for such a simple task, when Perl's `printf` behaves exactly like the C equivalent in your shell example?

Answer (score 4):

In `awk` you can use the `int()` function to truncate the values of a floating point number to make it integer.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f
3.49     will be 3
2.9      will be 3
4.1      will be 4
23.51    will be 24
982.4999 will be 982

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{x=int($1); print $0,x}' f
3.49     will be 3 3
2.9      will be 3 2
4.1      will be 4 4
23.51    will be 24 23
982.4999 will be 982 982
```

#### To Round off you can do something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{x=$1+0.5; y=int(x); print $0,y}' f
3.49     will be 3 3
2.9      will be 3 3
4.1      will be 4 4
23.51    will be 24 24
982.4999 will be 982 982
```

#### Note: I am not sure how you would like to handle `numbers like 2.5`. The above method will return `3 for 2.5`.

Comment: Aah, my bad … so what should the value be if it is `2.5`?

Comment: You would have to ask the OP. Math::Round seems to round "towards infinity", i.e. positive numbers up, negative numbers down.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of ksh that do non-integer math probably have floor(), trunc(), and round() functions.  Can't check 'em all, but at least on my Mac (Lion), I get this:

```
$ y=3.49
$ print $(( round(y) ))
3
$ y=3.51
$ print $(( round(y) ))
4
$ (( p = round(y) ))
$ print $p
4
$
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl, `my $i = int($f+0.5);`. Should be similar in the other, assuming they have a convert to integer or floor function. Or, if like in javascript, they have a `Math.round` function which could be used directly.

Comment: how to run this perl syntax in ksh script ?

Comment: ROUNDED=$(perl -e 'print int($ARGV[0] + 0.5)' $REALVALUE) would accomplish this in the script

Comment: For bash, you can go to http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial and search for "Round floating point number" and find a solution that utilize printf for the same. Probably similar in ksh.