# Get the value before decimal point

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, decimal-point

I am writing a Bash script. I have a variable in it which is a float value. For example:

```
x=2099.2
```

I need the value before decimal point, i.e, only `2099`.

Comment: this might help you, check the accepted answer


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777070/linux-ksh-round-down-or-round-up-float-numbers

Comment: You can also use `${x%%.*}` to strip everything from the dot.

Comment: What is a `bsh` script? It's unclear if you really mean `ksh` like your tags suggest or `bash`.

Comment: fedorqui- Your answer is working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following shell parameter expansion:

```
${x%%.*}
```

This removes everything from the first dot.

See it live:

```
$ v=203.4
$ echo ${v%%.*}
203

$ v=2.3.4
$ echo ${v%%.*}
2
```

From [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${parameter%%word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the  longest matching pattern deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.